# How to mark query as idempotent in spring-data-cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql3, spring-data-cassandra

I'm migrating from code that uses Cassandra java driver directly to a `spring-data-cassandra`. Old code used `com.datastax.driver.core.PreparedStatement#setIdempotent` to mark some queries as `idempotent` (that provides performance/latency bonus in some cases)

Is there any way to set this property when working through `spring-data-cassandra` or through `spring-cql`? I would expect it to be an option for `@Query` annotation, or a separate annotation on query method, or at least a part of `QueryOptions`

The only related thing I found is https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-403 , looks like `org.springframework.cassandra.core.CachedPreparedStatementCreator` that is used at `CassandraTemplate`, does not support idempotent flag (and even resets this flag for manually-built queries). Moreover, I did not find any mention at 2.0 `spring-data-cassandra` branch on github

Comment: No, it's not planned for 2.0 yet because the caching is broken and the whole point of idempotent query is to make it cacheable. There won't be a built in support for this flag until caching issues are fixed. When I looked at this issue, https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-291 was the main culprit (IMHO) that was blocking this flag from being usable

Comment: Could you please paste this comment as an answer so I can mark current question as resolved?

Comment: For now, please implement your own `PreparedStatementCreator` (with caching, if necessary). Would be great if you share your thoughts about idempotent statements in https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-403.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not planned for 2.0 yet because the caching is [broken](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-403?focusedCommentId=135486&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-135486) and the whole point of idempotent query is to make it cacheable.

There won't be a built in support for this flag until caching issues are fixed. When I looked at this issue, https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-291 was the main culprit (IMHO) that was blocking this flag from being usable